Why can I consider the values of n uniform(0,1) i.i.d's evenly spaced for expectation?
Essentially this idea came up while I was doing two separate questions
a. A bee wants to fly on the real line from the point $0$ to the point $1$, visiting $n$ flowers which are positioned at the points
$$
\begin{array}{c}
{\displaystyle\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{2}{n+1},\ldots,\frac{n}{n+1}}
\\[1mm] \left(\ \mbox{here}\ n\ \mbox{is some fixed positive integer}\ \right)
\end{array}
$$
The bee chooses at random, with equal probabilities, one of the $n!$ possible orderings of the flowers. It flies from $0$ to the first flower, from there to the second flower, and so on through all the flowers in the chosen order, before flying on to $1$.What is the expected total distance it will fly?
b. What is the expected sum of the largest k of n Unif(0,1) random variables.
In both of these solutions, we can consider  (because of symmetry) the random variables as partitioning the interval into evenly sized pieces, namely, into pieces of size $\frac{1}{n+1}$. I'm not seeing exactly what the symmetry is here that allows us to do this?
In the given solution for question a, it says to imagine the unit interval wrapped up into a circle by identifying 0 and 1, then the three arcs have endpoints drawn from an evenly distributed set of $n+1$ points and thus the expected length of each arc is the same. I kind of understand this but don't see why the expected length of each arc is the same. Also it seems question a is a sort of discrete, without replacement analogue of question b.
What is the symmetry and how can we consider the random variables as partitioning the interval into evenly sized intervals?

I do not quite understand the suggested solution to the first question.  I would have thought the initial flight from $0$ and the final flight to $1$ would have expectation $\frac12$ while the $n-1$ flights between flowers would have a lower expectation $\frac13$ making the expected total flight distance $\frac12 + \frac{n-1}{3} + \frac12 = \frac{n+2}{3}$ not $\frac{n+1}{3}$.  This is easily checked for $n=1$ and for $n=2$.

Hi Henry, Yeah That's right, I didn't put the full answer to the question, just the bit that relates to how we get the (n-1)/3, that is, why it is evenly distributed.  The full solution is available at link problem number 18.

The total distance is:
$$Y=\underbrace{(1-X_n)}_{\textrm{last trip}}+\sum_{2\leq k \leq  n}|X_k-X_{k-1}|+\underbrace{X_1}_{\textrm{first trip}}$$
The variables $(X_k)_{1\leq k \leq n}$ are chosen uniformly without replacement from $\{1/(n+1),...,n/(n+1)\}$. By linearity of expectation and the fact that, by symmetry, $E[X_n]=E[X_{n-1}]=...=E[X_1]$ and $E[|X_{n}-X_{n-1}|]=...=E[|X_{2}-X_{1}|]$ we get
$$E[Y]=1+(n-1)E[|X_{2}-X_{1}|]$$
and
$$E[|X_{2}-X_{1}|]=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{1\leq \ell,k \leq n}|k-\ell|\frac{1}{n(n-1)}=\frac{1}{3}$$
so
$$E[Y]=1+\frac{n-1}{3}=\frac{n+2}{3}$$

Yeah that's exactly what I did and I got that, my question was asking about what the 'symmetry' argument you've used to say that the expectation of the increments are the same. I think it makes sense since if each of the R.Vs are identical and uniformly sampled, the expected difference between any two consecutive steps should be the same. That is, imagine we are picking flowers randomly, they partition the whole length into $n+1$ increments that must be equal size, and add up to 1, hence they are each of length $\frac{1}{n+1}$.

@JerryMahajan I believe that the formal justification of symmetry here would be exchangeability of $(X_k)_{1\leq k \leq n}$ - do have a look at it and let me know if it convinces you.

In the first question, the argument that the intermediate flights all have the same expected distance is based on them all having the same distribution, and that comes from their start and finish points being equally likely to be any pair of the flowers, since all $n!$ orderings are equally likely.  You can then use linearity of expectation to get the expected total flight as $\frac12 + \frac13(n-1)+\frac12 = \frac{n+2}{3}$.
That argument does not depend on the flowers being planted equal distances apart.
Suppose instead the $n$ flowers were at positions $\frac12, \frac14, \ldots, \frac1{2^n}$.   Finding the expected length of an intermediate flight would be a little more complicated but possible as it is  $\frac{(n-3)+2^{-n}(n+3)}{\frac12 n(n-1)}$ and multiplying this by $n-1$ and adding $1$ for the combined expected lengths of the first and last flight would give $\frac{(3n-6)+2^{-n}(2n+6)}{n}$ by precisely the same argument that the $n-1$ intermediate flights all have the same distribution and so the same expected length. Interestingly, in this example extra flowers eventually only make a small difference to the total expected flight, which has a limit of $3$ as $n$ increases, while in the original question the total expected flight was $O(n)$.
